# Would appreciate help! What is wrong with the ESC?

Tags: esc, first-person-view, long-range-drone, esc-protocol, fc-firmware

Hear the beep when I connect a battery and when I connect a battery and the FC has voltage...

Sounds like there is a voltage drop...but could it also be a new noise?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/11sILUhndjzrdEx5IC8zfw7DDL-PQ4z28/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/11vbh9222wxzbsfajSwe7KNMCx8ghZB7T/view?usp=sharing

For those who cannot see the videos.

When you connect only the battery, the ESC beeps three times, then one more time, three times, then two times.

When you connect a battery and the FC already has a USB connected, the ESC makes three beeps and then two beeps (that's how it should be...)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the FC is not arming the ESC for some reason. The best way to solve arming problems is to connect up the VTX and see what warning message BetaFlight is showing in the OSD.

Also, in the second video, some of the beeps (the loud ones) are coming from your beeper, which is triggered by the FC.

Comment: This is correct for arming the flight controller, however the ESC will still arm (beep correctly) if there are errors in the flight controller prohibiting it from arming